# How to append a button to end of datagrid? (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've got a `DataGrid` with n-rows in it. When the user reaches the end of the `DataGrid`, there should be a button to load more rows (like you know from some websites). How can I position that button, which always stays at the end of the `DataGrid`?

I'm using C# and WPF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the Template of the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <DataGrid.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="ADD"/>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Template>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: But why there is so much gap between datagrid and button?

Comment: @robot that's probably because your datagrid does not contain enough items. or you can just use a stack panel instead of dock panel