# WPF datagrid add button after autogenerated columns

Tags: wpf, templates, button, datagrid, styles

I have a wpf app, where a datagrid has autogeneratedcolumns, and I want after that columns add two more containing buttons, I've tried working with datagridtemplatecolumn and code, but nothing. Any help? Thanks...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>                                            
       <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Tag="{Binding Category}">Edit</Button>
     </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append a button to end of datagrid? (WPF, C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408986/how-to-append-a-button-to-end-of-datagrid-wpf-c)

Comment: Do you want the buttons added to each and every row? Can you give an example of what you tried that isn't working?

Comment: yes, buttons added to each and every row, I edit the question and there's the code, I'm using resource dictionary for the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, thanks! Here is the solution, just in case... :)

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
 <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Hidden"/>
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding Category}" />
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Birthday">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Button Content="Edit" />
     </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```