# How to Control Sequence of columns automatically Generated in DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have DataGrid, it looks like:

[image]

> But I want it to be like:
>
> [image]

I tried to add `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`, but then it looks like:

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ItemsSource="{Binding TableComments}" x:Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button  Command="{Binding DataContext.AddCommand, ElementName=dataGrid}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dataGrid}">Add</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How to achive the result that I want? i.e buttons to the right, and other columns to the left( and their content's horizontalalign to left)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF datagrid add button after autogenerated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068294/wpf-datagrid-add-button-after-autogenerated-columns)

Comment: @Sinatr How to bing the data to the column(column withot the button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set DataGrid property

```
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

And manually add comment column. And from this point you are free of customization.

Comment: Here is helpfull link https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/

Comment: "And manually add comment column" what do you mean, there is a binding between the  DataGrid and datatable

Comment: You can create column manually with databinding as in link I attached.

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding _Fild you want to Bind_ }/>